# make images picked using react-native-image-crop-picker to be png

Tags: react-native

so am using react-native-image-crop-picker to pick images but the images am getting are all in jpg format. even i select a png file.

this code so far

```
 ImagePickerCropper.openPicker({
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
          cropping: true,
          includeBase64: true,
          mediaType: "photo",
          freeStyleCropEnabled: true,
        })
          .then((images) => {
            console.log('...image----', images);
            onFileSelected(images.data);
          })
          .catch((error) => {});
```

Comment: this forked has fixed this problem https://github.com/KarlosQ/react-native-image-crop-picker/  you can install react-native-image-crop-picker from github repo instead of npm package:

`yarn add github:KarlosQ/react-native-image-crop-picker/`

Comment: @shammi is there any configuration i need to do apart from installing from that repo you suggested